# How to hide MS Access parent MDI window, yet still show the Windows Taskbar reference?

Tags: windows, forms, ms-access, vba

I have utlized the User32 library from MS Access in VBA to Hide the MDI window:

```
Global Const SW_HIDE = 0
Global Const SW_SHOWNORMAL = 1
Global Const SW_SHOWMINIMIZED = 2
Global Const SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED = 3

' Windows User32 Library reference to modify the window by one of the above commands
Private Declare Function apiShowWindow Lib "User32" Alias "ShowWindow" _
 (ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal nCmdShow As Long) As Long
```

At the appropriate point in my application I have triggered a call to this function effectively hiding the application while specific forms are set with `Modal = True` and `Popup = True` to have them show through the hidden parent MDI window.

This works great! However, I would like to still have a reference on the windows Taskbar for the open instance of MS Access:

[image: Windows Taskbar]

This functionality went away once I hid the parent MDI window. Previously the user could click on this reference order to bring focus back to the respective open form.

Does anyone know how I can accomplish this? Is there a User32 Library reference or parameter which could be passed into the `apiShowWindow` method to have this occur?

Comment: Why do you feel you must hide the parent window? This is exactly the kind of reason you have it, so it makes it easy for the user to navigate. Get used to default behaviors and live with them. Then you won't end up doing all kinds of Byzantine things that break other functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

why not just make the call with SW_SHOWMINIMIZED?  that seems to be the desired functionality. (e.g. window not showing but still on taksbar vs. window totally hidden)

Comment: This worked perfectly! Thank you. For some reason, it didn't even dawn on me to try that.